# hit exception while trying to submit data to Azure db

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, azure, asp.net-identity

I have a post form where the user can enter in a title and a description for their post. There is also a submit button that shoots off my `Submit_Post` event.

Everything seems to run fine up until I try to `saveChanges()` on my database.

```
protected void Submit_Post(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (website_dbEntities objEnt = new website_dbEntities())
    {

        Post postData = new Post()
        {
            PostTitle = txtPostTitle.Text,
            PostDescription = txtPostDescription.Text,
        };

        //Add post data to db
        objEnt.Posts.Add(postData);
        objEnt.SaveChanges();    //hits exception here
    }
}
```

This is the exception I am getting:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

I have tried a few different things, how can I fix this?

Comment: What are the different things you have already tried? What does the debugger tell you about the data being added - does the data look ok? Please inspect the exception to see if it has an inner exception. All the .aspx stuff will not be related to the problem, so you may want to remove it - people will be more willing to help if they do not have to read through loads of irrelevant code :-)

Comment: I have tried taking the `SaveChanges()` out and looking for something different, and looked online for different solutions. The debugger says that their was an error while trying to update the entries, and too view the inner exception for more details, how do I do this? The data I am entering is "test" in both fields.

Answer (score 2):

Posting this as a community wiki since it's not an "answer" per se, but being able to clearly see which properties are preventing the update has saved me numerous times:

```
try
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
        .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
        .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

    var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
    var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);
    throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
}
```

What this does is actually add the individual property validation errors to the exception you get on the yellow screen of death. So instead of unhelpfully just being told EF failed to update, you see *why* it failed to update. This should help you determine the source of your problem.

Comment: using this right now, definitely is incredibly helpful. The issue is with one of my foreign keys.